# Prove these subgroups are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to solve this question which I found very complex and difficult due to the amount of details.

> Let $H, K, N$ be subgroups of a group G such that $H\leq K$, $H\cap N
> =K\cap N$, and $HN=KN$. Show that $H=K$.

I'm trying to prove it using this:

[image: 1]

and this:

[image: 2]

Am I in the right way? I really need a hand here, there are so many data in this question and I'm a little confused.

Comment: I fixed your LaTeX and hosted the images elsewhere, as TinyPic is quite a mess.

Comment: It may be wiser to prove $H=K$

Comment: @JackSchmidt yes yes sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is $H \le K$, and your conclusion is $H = K$.

We already know $H \subseteq K$, let's show the opposite inclusion $K \subseteq H$.

Let $a \in K$. Then $a = a \cdot 1 \in KN = HN$, so $a = b n$ for some $b \in H$, $n \in N$. Thus $b^{-1} a = n \in K \cap N = H \cap N \subseteq H$, so $b^{-1} a \in H$, which means $a \in H$.

---

> Note that this is related to [Dedekind's modular identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), which states that if $N$ is a <strike>normal</strike> subgroup of a group $G$, and $H \le K \le G$, then
>   $$K \cap N H = (K \cap N) H.\tag{Ded}$$
>   This is a vestigial form of the distributive property, and lies at the core of the current argument.
>
> In fact, using (Ded) and the hypotheses in OP one has
>   $$
> K = K \cap NK = K \cap N H = (K \cap N) H = (H \cap N) H = H.
> $$

The **proof of (Ded)** goes exactly like the argument above. Clearly the inclusion $\supseteq$ holds. Conversely, let $a = n b \in K \cap N H$, with $a \in K$, $n \in N$, $b \in H$. Thus $a b^{-1} = n \in K \cap N$, so $a = (a b^{-1}) b \in (K \cap N) H$.

Comment: in order to use dedekind's argument, $N$ has to be a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @user74141, you're right, it does not appears to be needed. If it is not normal, there's no guarantee that $MH$ is a subgroup, but it appears not to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition:** If $H \leq K$, $H\cap N = K \cap N$, and $HN=KN$, then $H=K$.

*Hint:* Write an element of $K \leq KN =HN$ as an element of $HN$. A couple of arithmetic steps shows this element is already in $H$.

> *Proof:* Write $k \in K \leq KN = HN$ as $k=hn$, then $n=h^{-1}k \in K \cap N = H \cap N$, so both $h$ and $h^{-1}k$ are in $H$, so their product $k$ is also in $H$ and $K \leq H$. $\square$

Comment: Why $K \leq KN$? thank you for your answer.

Comment: KN = { kn : k in K, n in N }, but 1 in N, so k = k1 in KN.

Comment: yes yes, of course

Answer (score 0):

We have

- $H\lt K$
- $H\cap N =K\cap N$
- $HN=KN$

The second implies that:

- $\forall h = n,\,\,\, \exists k, \,\,\,h = n = k$
- $\forall k = n,\,\,\, \exists h, \,\,\,h = n = k$

The third implies

- $\forall hn,\,\,\, \exists k\bar n,\,\,\, hn = k \bar n$
- $\forall k \bar n,\,\,\, \exists h n,\,\,\, hn = k \bar n$

and putting $n,\bar n = 1$ gives

- $\forall h,\,\,\, \exists k n,\,\,\, h = k n$
- $\forall k,\,\,\, \exists h n,\,\,\, k = h n$

since $H < K$ the first is trivial so we will take the second as the starting point.

---

For all $k$ there exists $h$, $n$ such that $k = h n$ or $h^{-1} k = n$ LHS is $\in K$ and RHS is $\in N$ so exists $\bar h$ such that $k = h n = h \bar h$.

This shows that every element of $K$ may be written in elements from $H$.